# 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server"

Tags: html, vb.net

hey guys i'm building a website for a school assignment and i want to create a multi line text box but when i do i get the error "'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server" I've looked it over and it wouldn't go away by inserting a form tag with runat server before the text box code. how can i fix this? here's the code:

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" Runat="Server">
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
<div id="body">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</form>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Any ASP.NET Server control (Web/HTML) must be placed inside the `<form runat="server">`

Comment: is this the content in a master page? or a normal page inherited from master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the form tag from your content page - the form tag on the master page will be sufficient. You will need the `ContentPlaceHolder` tags on the master page to be within the form for this to work.

like

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div>
           <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="bodycontent" runat="server">

           </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
       </div>
 </form>
```